# Confused by process of writing PERT chart

Tags: critical-path

This is not a homework question but arises from self-study with full access to the answers. I'm not looking for the answers, but rather how to arrive at them.

---

I'm having trouble understanding how to solve a question on completing a PERT chart.

My confusion is as to how I could know which arrow has which label without any info on dependencies. e.g. from milestone C, how could it be decided which of the arrows should be labeled with B and which with C?

Also, shouldn't module testing end after writing the module code?

I'd like to know the thought process of an expert solving this. E.g: "This must be B because such and such is true."

[image]

Comment: Hi Robin, welcome to PM.SE! As your question stands, it looks like a homework question, not a real life problem.. and thus likely to be closed. The community isn't likely to answer you that 2 to 3 is B and 3 to 4 is C because it'd add no value to the broader community. Instead, focus your question on why you don't understand - based on your own research - why you should answer one thing or other. An example of a good question like this is [THIS](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/25622/are-all-nodes-in-activity-on-arrow-diagrams-milestones).