# How can we show milestones in Activity on Arrow diagrams?

Tags: milestones

In a AoA (Activity-on-Arrow) diagrams we use arrows to show the activities, what if we want to show a milestone in an AoA diagram in such a way that its effect can be seen in network activities and time calculations?

Comment: I'm not familiar with AoA, but it seems you could just label a node (event) as a milestone, or am I misunderstanding the question? In essence, a milestone doesn't have an "effect", it is just a point in the project plan where prerequisite activities have been finished and for which a completion date can be estimated.

Comment: This [closely-related question](https://pm.stackexchange.com/q/25622/4271) may already have an answer. If not, please explain how your question is different, or why the other AoA questions on this site don't address your particular use case.

Comment: All nodes are milestones on AoA. Please consider expanding your question with examples of what you've tried and why that doesn't work for you, or your question may be closed pending clarification.